# TypeError with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

when I use this function which triggered when something changes in `/drivers/{wilayaid}/{driverid}/proposed` .. it gives me `TypeError: change.after.get is not a function`

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/drivers/{wilayaid}/{driverid}/proposed').onUpdate(async (change) => {

    const fcm = change.after.get('fcm');

    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: "CLIQUE ICI",
            body: "NOUVELLE OFFRE DE TRANSPORTATION",
        },
        token: fcm,
    }

    let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(fcmToken);
    
});
```

I dont know why !!!

Comment: The error message is telling you that `change.after` does not have a method called "get" on it.  You might want to review the API documentation.

Comment: but it works here for firestore : exports.sendNotificationToUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{Uid}/posts/{Pid}').onWrite(async (event) => {
    let uid = event.after.get('phone');

Comment: Realtime Database does not have the same API as Firestore.  Follow the documentation and examples for the database you're using.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#onupdate
The `.get()` is also a promise... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html